# how can i identify the host environment using stencil web component?

Tags: angular, httpclient, stenciljs, rest

I am developing a custom stencil component which will have a dropdown with options fetched from my backend api. Using fetchapi i got the data to be shown. But this component will be integrated in angular application .so , how can i identify whether it is used in dev or prod? because i have to fetch data based on this . I am not sure how to get this info where i use my stencil component.

```
angular -  my-component.html
<div>
  <p>This is example of stenciljs</p>

  <my-dropdown (onChange)="onSelect($event)"></my-dropdown> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Build` context from Stencil:

```js
import { Build } from '@stencil/core';

if (Build.isDev) {
  // ...
} else {
  // this is a prod build
}
```

Dead code elimination will remove the code from your prod bundle, so you don't have to worry about exposure of dev-related code.